# Высота блока под картинку с "position: absolute"

Tags: css, html, position

У меня в блоке есть картинка со свойством "position", которое имеет значение "asbolute". Картинка намного больше блока, и мне бы хотелось, чтобы блок принимал её высоту. Как это можно реализовать (желательно без js)?

Comment: Скажите, а зачем такое нужно? Какую цель преследуете?

Comment: родительскому контейнеру задать **position: relative;** ?

Comment: к сожалению, данный метод не работает

Comment: @Marina это имеет значение?

Comment: @ЯрославЯсиницький Ну просто хочется понять, зачем проделывать подобное. Проще иногда узнать цель, чтобы грамотнее решить задачу. Стоит ли игра свеч)

Comment: @ЯрославЯсиницький Тогда быть может вы покажите ваш код? Задать родительскому контейнеру позицию relative означает ограничить абсолютное позицирование дочернего контейнера, отсчёт будет происходить от границ родительского. В ином случае от того элемента, где установлен этот атрибут.